# How it can be detected that the python script is running or stopped (in windows)

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I have a selenium test software(python) which is running on windows and it may be failed(halted) time to time, which in these cases i reset it by myself(manually).
my question is: how can i detect failure in test process and reset the software again by code.i just want to know that the file(for example "test.py") which i started before is running or stopped.

Comment: You could have a second Python script which calls your test script using something like `subprocess.Popen`. Then when the subprocess (your test script) exits with a non-zero exit code you can start it again in a loop.

Comment: But then what happens if the python script running the python script halts? You'll need something to make sure that that python script keeps running, the python script which keeps running the python script, and so on...

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately i am new in this field, so would you please refer me to some good references in this regards?.

Comment: @SPYBUG96 I don't see why this would be an issue, it's like saying there's no point using cron to schedule tasks in Linux because cron might not be running. In this case it's seems that the test script crashes and exits so needs to be restarted again. Which the wrapper script I'm suggesting would do. If written correctly there's no reason the wrapper should crash.

Comment: @Milad here is some documentation for `subprocess` https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: And a helpful tutorial here https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators

Comment: @JamieScott just bringing up the halting problem

Comment: thanks to Jamie and  SPYBUG96 for your good helps.